# How to extract positive and negative subnetworks from a singed network

Tags: python, networkx, canopy

With this code I found the list of all subgraphs, and then trying the extracting all positive and negative subnetworks but   did not find   any logic for this, can anyone help me

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.components.connected import connected_components
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.read_edgelist('/home/suman/Desktop/dataset/CA-GrQc.txt', create_using = None, nodetype=int,edgetype=int) 
H=nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)
for i in H:
    print list(i)  
pos=nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw(G,pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos=pos)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you give an example input and an example of your desired output?  What your code does right now is just look for components that are connected by edges (regardless of their sign).  Do you want to take the subnetworks made up of just the positive and just the negative edges and then find their components?

Comment: let me explain, i want to find Positive links,Negative links,Reciprocated links from any network dataset like(https://snap.stanford.edu/data/email-Enron.html)

Comment: It would be much clearer if you could give a minimal example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Saying you want to find positive links is different from saying you want to find a positive subnetwork.  Can you give a specific small example?

Comment: sir actually i am trying to upload here one image for explaining my problem but i am not able to upload this .

Comment: Please let me know whether my answer addresses your problem or not.  (and if it does please "accept" the answer - you should also do this on your previous question on deleting nodes from networks)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is to create the network made up of just negative edges and the network made up of just positive edges.

If so, here is some code to do that (**edited** to account for the fact that `add_edges_from` can handle weighted edges - I had misread the documentation):

```
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6)], weight = 1)
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)], weight = -1)

pos_edges = [(u,v,w) for (u,v,w) in G.edges(data=True) if w['weight']>0]
neg_edges = [(u,v,w) for (u,v,w) in G.edges(data=True) if w['weight']<0]

Hpos = nx.Graph()
Hneg = nx.Graph()

Hpos.add_edges_from(pos_edges)
Hneg.add_edges_from(neg_edges)

Hneg.edges(data=True)
> [(1, 2, {'weight': -1}),
 (2, 3, {'weight': -1}),
 (3, 4, {'weight': -1}),
 (4, 5, {'weight': -1})]
Hpos.edges(data=True)
> [(1, 3, {'weight': 1}),
 (2, 4, {'weight': 1}),
 (3, 5, {'weight': 1}),
 (4, 6, {'weight': 1})]
```

Please let me know if this is what you're after.  I have to go now so I can't give detailed explanation, but if you have some comments on what does/does not make sense, I will respond later.

Comment: if network list has not a weight then what conditions are apply  .like if i have a network dataset in text file  which contain only edgelist  then here i can't apply  (w['weight']>0) condition . then what i do here

Comment: I do not understand.  Please give a clear example of your input and what the output you want is.